# C++ "using Signature" in class

Tags: c++

In c++, what does the using Signature line do? I really dont get it, what is Signature?

```
class XX { 
public:
    using Signature = void(std::stringstream&&);    
}
```

Signature is further used once like this:

```
using Function = std::function<Signature>;
```

Comment: It is modern alternative to `typedef`

Comment: `Signature` is a [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) of a function that takes `std::stringstream&&` as parameter and returns `void`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really did not see this...